# Node.js return a JS file locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

Inside my html file, I am using this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, I was not allowed to connect to internet during the running. How can I use node js to return this file locally. I already download this file "jquery.min.js" in my local machine.

I am trying to use this code, but it does not work.

```
function callback(data) { 
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    var str = data+"";
    res.write(str);     
    res.end();
}
HTMLtemplate.load("jquery.min.js", callback);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to load jquery into your browser from a node server?  If so, just use node to serve some static assets and load them like <script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you please tell me more about it? I want to load jquery into my browser from node server. how to server static assets.

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: no. i don know what is express

Comment: If you can use Express with node.js, you can use the `.static()` function to serve static files automatically: http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html.  If you aren't going to use express, there are other modules explicitly for serving static files or you can code it yourself like this: http://ericsowell.com/blog/2011/5/6/serving-static-files-from-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily serve up both the web page and jquery in a simple node server that looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');


var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.end("Hello World\n");
});
server.listen(8000);
```

I think you are going to need some router or framework to serve up multiple http endpoints and static assets. Many people use express:

http://expressjs.com/

Or even something as simple as this:

https://github.com/creationix/node-router

I suppose you could serve up a web page with jquery embedded in it using a naked node server by doing something like this (this is only psuedo-code):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
 <script>REPLACEME</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>";

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    fs.readFile('jquery.js', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.end(html.replace('REPLACEME', data));

    });

});
server.listen(8000);
```

But that seems very wrong except, perhaps, as an exercise that demonstrates what a web framework does. Unless you are doing this for school, just install one of the above frameworks (or some other) and it will be easy.